# Typescript Angular FileReader

Tags: angularjs, typescript, image, upload, reader

I am trying to preview a loaded file in an angular project. But the code fails with `error TS2315: Type 'ProgressEvent' is not generic.`

Here is my code of reading the selected image

```
imageUploaded(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

        reader.onload = (resultEvent: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
            console.log(typeof resultEvent);
            this.iconLocalUrl = resultEvent.target.result.toString();
        };
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Three years and six months later, have you found out why